# Call a method that have throws IOException

Tags: android, ioexception

This is my code:

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment{

String mCurrentPhotoPath = "";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent(); // Here I try to call this method
    } catch (IOException dfg) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //dispatchTakePictureIntent(); //I can't call this like I did here

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
}

ImageView SkimmedImageImg;
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SkimmedImageImg = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.SkimmedImg);
}

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() throws IOException{
   ..CODE..
   photo = createImageFile();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    ..CODE..
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

}
```

How can I fix this problem?
I can't remove "throws IOException" from each functions, because I have to call "createImageFile()" and this doesn't works without "throws IOException".

Some ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you learned anything about exception handling? Specifically `try` or `catch`?

Comment: Your previous answer used it correctly... Why haven't you used that code? http://stackoverflow.com/a/42330491/2308683

Comment: "How can I fix this problem?" What problem? What is the specific error?

Answer (score 0):

In your code...

> ```
> //dispatchTakePictureIntent(); //I can't call this like I did here
> ```

Right... You can't call it without `try-catch`-ing. The method `throws`

---

Again, in your code

> ```
> try {
>     dispatchTakePictureIntent(); // Here I try to call this method
> } catch (IOException dfg) {
>     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> }
> ```

You called the method **fine**. You "caught" the exception that is being declared by `throws`.

If you want to actually "see" the error, don't Toast. That is a bad user-interface design to see a random pop-up.

Use a Log (and name `dfg` better)

```
catch (IOException ex) {
    Log.e("ERROR: dispatchTakePictureIntent", ex.getMessage());
}
```